# Dipole's centre equilibrium

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

I need an intuitive explanation of the mathematical result that there is no force acting in the centre of a dipole. Suppose we put a positive charge in the middle of the dipole, intuitively I think that the charge is attracted by the negative charge and rejected by the positive, so the charge must "fall"  on the negative charge. Why in the middle the charge should be in equilibrium? How can the forces be balanced? Where is my mistake?

Sorry for bad english

Comment: The claim as you are construing it is false for the reasons you state, but it is likely you're misinterpreting the text. It's impossible to tell without more context, though.

Comment: [The electric field of a dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Field_from_an_electric_dipole) is not zero at $r=0$ so the force on a charge is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, no one ever said that force at the middle point of the dipole is zero!(if you're thinking something about the equipotentials in this question, then please let me know).